# How to get result of second table while using joins in rails active record query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My ActiveRecord Query is `Note.joins(:user).where(category: "Actions")`
and its generating sql as `SELECT notes.* FROM notes INNER JOIN users ON users.id = notes.user_id WHERE notes.category = 'Actions'`

I want to get data from users table not from notes table means i am trying to generate sql as   `SELECT users.* FROM users INNER JOIN notes ON users.id = notes.user_id WHERE notes.category = 'Actions';`

What would be the Active Record query for it.

if i am doing `User.joins(:notes).where(category: "Actions")` then it throws error `Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users.category'` as category is attribute of notes table not of users table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this -

```
User.joins(:notes).where(notes: {category: "Actions"})
```

Comment: could you also tell me how can we pass conditional operators with .where method in AR.
eg: `Note.where(notes: {feeling_score: 7})` will always give  `SELECT notes.* FROM notes  WHERE notes.feeling_score = 7` how can i pass conditional operator like `<`,`<=` in where clause.

Comment: User.joins(:notes).where("notes.feeling_score <  ? ", 7 ) @ArvindMehra